# How to correctly Dispose a class deriving from FileAppender in log4net

Tags: c#, log4net, dispose

let's suppose I've a class that inherits from the `log4net.Appender.FileAppender` type because I've to provide some custom log functionalities and that class owns an unmanaged resource.

In the below code I report the definition of the class and the implementation of the Disposable pattern.

```
public class MyLogFileAppender : FileAppender, IDisposable
{
     private IDisposable _myUnmanagedResource;

     #region Other methods used for flushing and so on are here.
     #endregion

     public void Dispose()
     {
         Dispose(true);
     }

     protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
     {
         if (disposing)
         {
             _myUnmanagedResource?.Dispose();
         }
     }
}
```

My question is: how and when call the Dispose method? I would be nice if it's called by the underlying log4net system but I think that is not the case and I should manually invoke it.

Comment: Separate, but: are you sure that `_myUnmanagedResource` is actually unmanaged? If it's `IDisposable` then it's a .NET class, and it's managed. Unmanaged resources are things like pointers to memory allocated outside of .NET

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper way to shutdown a logger instance in log4Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892916/proper-way-to-shutdown-a-logger-instance-in-log4net)

Comment: @canton7 yes sorry maybe I chose a bad name, but I mean an instance that uses an unmanaged resource and should be disposed. For example, in my actual case, that is a ManualResetEvent.